# Does configuration on tkinter buttons always work?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a code that has all the letters on the screen as buttons. When you click the button, the background color should become red and the button should become disabled. Here's what I have so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
import string as s

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Test')
root.geometry('1100x1100+10+10')

letters = tk.Frame(root)
letters.place(x=500, y=300)
letter_dict = {l:n for n, l in enumerate(s.ascii_lowercase)}
letter_buttons = [(tk.Button(letters, text=(l.upper()), padx=20, pady=20, font=('Times New Roman', '25'), state='normal', command=lambda l=l: take_out_button(l))) for l in s.ascii_lowercase]

def place_lt_btns():
    global letter_buttons
    #letter_buttons[0].grid(row=0, column=0)
    columnnum = 0
    rownum = 0
    for num, i in enumerate(letter_buttons):
        if num < 24:
            i.grid(row=rownum, column=columnnum)
            columnnum += 1
            if columnnum == 6:
                rownum += 1
                columnnum = 0
        else:
            if num == 24:
                i.grid(row=4, column=2)
            elif num == 25:
                i.grid(row=4, column=3)

place_lt_btns()

def take_out_button(l):
    n = letter_dict[l]
    letter_buttons[n].config(bg='red', state='disabled')
```

Clearly, I am using `.config` to change the bg to 'red' and the state to be 'disabled'. It seems odd that one is working and one is not... Does anyone know why? The error is that the background isn't changing to red for the letter button when it is clicked.

Comment: Your code works for me when I add `root.mainloop()` after `place_lt_btns()`

Comment: Hmm... @quamrana it still doesn't work for me even with mainloop. I'm on mac. The background should change to red and it's not happening...

Comment: I'm on a PC and I can substitute (eg) `bg='green'` and the buttons will turn green (and become disabled).

Comment: You can't change the background color of buttons on OSX.

Comment: Oh okay that explains it @BryanOakley thanks!